# Using field data with javascript in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I'm having trouble calling the field data in some javascript.

Basically I need:

```
videoFilename = 'Name that user puts into Video Name field'
```

I thought perhaps i could just add it like in a workflow, but i'm not seeing an option for that.

Comment: I guess we need a bit more information on this. What are you trying to achieve? is the javascript in edit- or newform?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the XML via REST?

```
http://contoso.com/_api/lists/getbytitle('Listname')/items
```

Then you should get the XML output and can check what the column is called.
e.G. I get my Attachment Url and Attachment Description like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Rest URL
        var requestUri = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Marketplace')/items?$select=Title,ID,Attachments,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles";

            $.ajax({
                url: requestUri,
                type: "GET",
                headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data.d.results, function (i, item){
                        var title = item.Title;
                        var id = item.ID;
                        var attachmentUrl = item.AttachmentFiles.results[0];

                        //alert(attachmentUrl.FileName);
                        //alert(attachmentUrl.ServerRelativeUrl);

                    })
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error getting the Marketplace Items");
                }                     
            });
      });      

</script>
```

Maybe this will help you to get your Video filename.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding it by searching the nearest td.

```
var videoFilename = $('h3:contains("Video Filename")').closest('td').next('td').text().trim(),
```